# DevExpress MVC ComboBoxFor using TextField instead of ValueField when submitting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I use a DevExpress.ComboBoxFor in a view.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(actionName: "DetailPartialAction", controllerName: "CeduleDepartementale", ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "target" }))
{
  @Html.DevExpress().LabelFor(x => x.CeduleDateFrom) 
  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CeduleDateFrom) 
  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CeduleDateTo) 
  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CeduleDateTo) 
  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.WorkCenter) 
  @Html.DevExpress().ComboBoxFor(x => x.WorkCenter, 
  settings => 
               { 
                 settings.Name = "WorkCenter"; 
                 settings.Width = 180; 
                 settings.SelectedIndex = 0; 
                 settings.Properties.TextField = "Name"; 
                 settings.Properties.ValueField = "No"; 
                 settings.Properties.ValueType = typeof (string); 
}).BindList(CeduleProduction.Repository.Concrete.WorkCenterRepository
.GetAll()).GetHtml() 

<input type="submit" value="OK"/>}
```

When I submit the form, the valuefield is not used , it's the textfield , what do I have to change to allow the value (not shown) to be passed and not the textfield which is shown

Comment: what is the type of ``WorkCenter`` property?

Comment: can you show your model definition?

Comment: @SerenityNow can you show us the code of the controller that handles the combo value server side?

Comment: I wish i could, but i have move on from that company more than 3 years ago with no access to my code.

Comment: One of the reasons why ValueField may not be used is that ValueField  is always null